# Compare dictionary key with value and identify mismatch with python

Tags: python-3.x

I have following dictionary:

```
dict1 = { 
    '10.10.10.0/24':'net-10.10.10.10-24',
    '10.10.1.0/27':'net-10.10.1.0-27',
    '10.8.8.1':'host-10.8.8.1-32',
    '8.8.8.8/32':'hst-8.8.8.8',
    '192.168.10.1':'hst-186.20.12.1-32'
    }
```

I was looking the way that could detect any mismatch just between key ip address (subnet is not relevant for the moment) and valu ip address for example the last key 192.68.10.1 not matchs with 186.20.12.1.
I attemped to apply an slice or replace for the elements before to be added to the dictionary but it didnt work well.
How would be the most appropiated way for identify the discrepancy?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could iterate over `dict1.items()`, extract the IPv4 addresses with a regex and compare them?

Comment: What of the first item? Is it not a mistmatch?

Comment: Please show what you tried already and how exactly it went wrong so we can help. You aren't expecting to just get free code are you? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If keys and values in your dictionary follows format from the question, you can use this script (subnet is not taking in account by this script):

```
import re

dict1 = {
    '10.10.10.0/24':'net-10.10.10.10-24',
    '10.10.1.0/27':'net-10.10.1.0-27',
    '10.8.8.1':'host-10.8.8.1-32',
    '8.8.8.8/32':'hst-8.8.8.8',
    '192.168.10.1':'hst-186.20.12.1-32'
}

r = re.compile(r'\d+')

for k, v in dict1.items():
    if [*map(int, r.findall(k))][:4] != [*map(int, r.findall(v))][:4]:
        print('{} {} mismatch!'.format(k, v))
```

Prints:

```
10.10.10.0/24 net-10.10.10.10-24 mismatch!
192.168.10.1 hst-186.20.12.1-32 mismatch!
```

Comment: How can that be? The first one doesn't match as well... (`10.10.10.0` vs. `10.10.10.10`)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Good catch! It should be `[:4]` not `[:3]`